# Create a Store from a subset of JSON Store

Tags: javascript, json, extjs4

I have a JSON store defined as follows

```
var subAccountStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
  autoLoad: true,
  proxy: {
    type:'ajax',
    url : '/opUI/json/subaccount.action?name="ABC"'
  },
  fields: ['accountName', 'quantity','accountNumbers'],
  listeners: {
    load: function(store, records, success) {
      // ???????
    },
    single: true
  }
});
```

and sample data is

```
[{"accountName":"'ABC'","quantity":100,"accountNumbers":['12345A','12345B','12345C']},{"accountName":"'XYZ'","quantity":100,"accountNumbers":['99999A','99999B','99999C']}]
```

**How do I create a store dynamically for `accountNumbers` and assign to combo box inside the grid?**

Thanks
Tharahan

Answer (score 0):

For account numbers you have to declare a store separately. For example, in the panel items

```
items: [{
xtype: 'combobox',
id: 'addObjectComboCopy',
fieldLabel: '<h style= "color:red;">*</h> accountNumbers',
store: addFormStore,
displayField: 'select',
valueField: 'name',
editable: false,
allowBlank: false
```

}]

Here Store have to declare as shown below

```
var addFormStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields: ['name', 'select'],
data: [
    {"name": "01", "select": "12345A"},
    {"name": "02", "select": "12345B"},
    {"name": "03", "select": "12345C"}
]
```

});